In C Programming, why do we use %f and not %d to find sqrt(16) though it is just a positive integer?
Why do we have to use %f and not %d in the execution of ...
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("%f", sqrt(16));
}

If I use %d in place of %f then I get some error while compiling.

sqrt always returns a floating point value (float/double). %d is for int.

Why do you believe sqrt( 16 ) returns an integer value, and not a floating point value?

@Katastrophi The compiler issues error messages specially for you. Why do not you read error messages?

Could you please share the exact error message? @Katastrophi

in actual math, sqrt(16) is indeed an integer (4), but computers work differently

sqrt is a function that returns double, do casting like this: printf("%d", (int)sqrt(16)); it will work.

@HamzaAlAjlouni ... it will work. Are you sure about that?  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

@Andrew Henle, thank you for the information, I didn't know that before.

I am changing my comment: doing casting like this: printf("%d", (int)sqrt(16));  will technically do the casting but in some cases, casting is not going to work as you expect.

sqrt returns a double even for integer values (in the mathematical sense), so you must tell printf it's a double passed to it.

In some languages, functions can return values of different type. In such a language, sqrt could return a double in some circumstances, and int in others.
C is not such a language. The value returned by a function is always the same. For sqrt, this is a double. Even if the value is an integer in the mathematical sense, it's still returned as a double, not an int.
(Some might refer to this as weakly-typed vs stringly-typed, but those are meaningless terms.)
This means that sqrt returns a double even for integer values (in the mathematical sense), so you must tell printf it's a double passed to it.
If you want to convert the double to an int, you can use a cast.
printf( "%f",      sqrt( 16 ) );  // Correct
printf( "%d", (int)sqrt( 16 ) );  // Also correct*

Note that truncating a double by casting it to an int can result in surprising results. Some amount of rounding is often needed.
